# How to update data in run time?

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

I'm trying to update my data grid in runtime but it throws some error, and the data does not save in the database.

I'm using this code for the update command

```
Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
    Try
        ReviewBindingSource.EndEdit()
        ReviewTableAdapter.Update(MasterDataSet2.Review)
        MessageBox.Show("Data saved")
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub
```

[image: Error Image]

Comment: That error means that your table adapter has no value set for its `UpdateCommand` property. That property should be auto-generated but it cannot be if the system cannot identify a unique key for the data.  That can happen if the query involves multiple tables or it involves one table without a primary key. The latter is the most common culprit.  Database tables should pretty much always have a primary key.

Comment: By the way, why do you think that we should have to navigate to another site to see a picture of some text?  DO NOT post links to useless screenshots.  An error message is text.  Post it as text.

Comment: Note that fixing your database by adding a PK to your table(s) will not automatically fix the table adapter(s).  You need to re-run the configuration wizard from the Data Sources window.